# Why does my USB flash disk contiune heating while it is unmounted?

Tags: usb, unmounting

I am using Debian-Buster Linux. I use a USB flash disk to mount when I need it.   When i am done, I unmount(using umount) it without unplugging it. However, it continues to heat up(like it is being used) while it is unmounted. Why does it contiune to heat up? How can I prevent this problem?

Comment: it is still plugged in ... why do you say that it is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278982/should-be-usb-stick-drives-be-hot-to-touch-when-idle

The answer to your second question: unplug it.

Comment: For your USB flash it doesn't matter whether it's mounted or just plugged in sitting idly.